# Qt::make_shared for creating QSharedPtr as std::make_shared for creating std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, smart-pointers

As stated in Bjarne Stroustrup's "A tour of C++", and as a known C++14 practice, one should avoid naked `new` and `delete` in the code. Standard library offers `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` for creating smart pointers to immediately store allocated objects in.

However, it is not possible to use these routines for non-standard smart pointers, like in Qt. Qt has its own memory management model (with parents), but also provides smart pointer classes like `QSharedPointer` and `QPointer` (though the latter is not actually an owning pointer).

My question is: isn't it convenient to create Qt analogs of `std::make_shared`? Like this, for creating `QSharedPtr`:

```
namespace Qt
{
  template<class T, class... Args>
  QSharedPointer<T> make_shared(Args&&... args)
  {
    return QSharedPointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
}
```

Or like this, for creating `QPointer`:

```
namespace Qt
{
  template<class T, class... Args>
  QPointer<T> make_ptr(Args&&... args)
  {
     return QPointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }
}
```

And it can be used like:

```
auto pCancelButton = Qt::make_ptr<QPushButton>("Cancel", this);
```

Are there any caveats for this approach? Are there any publicly known usage of this approach?

**UPDATE** I claim that `Qt::make_ptr` is useful as long as `QPointer` is useful, because it will hide `new` operator and make sure `new` is called only for something that inherits `QObject`. Qt users do a lot of `new`'s, but in this way we can be sure `new` is used only in Qt context. Any arguments on this thought?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#create-2

Comment: @PiotrS. Brilliant! What about `QPointer`?

Comment: `make_with_parent` would be better than `make_ptr` because the important thing is that the object's lifetime is managed by the parent. The specific type of non-owning pointer used to refer to the object is irrelevant. Forcing the use of `QPointer` would add unnecessary overhead in cases where a raw pointer would be sufficient.

Comment: In the case of `QPointer` it probably wouldn't make sense to combine the allocation of storage for the object and storage for the refcount in a single allocation of heap memory, because the refcount would be expected to outlive the object.

Answer (score 20):

Features such as `make_shared` strictly rely on the *perfect forwarding* feature, which is only available since C++11 and the introduction of *universal (forwarding) references*. Having said that, without a *perfect forwarding*, using this function may be inefficient. Qt is quite older than the recent C++ standard, hence it was not available till Qt 5.1 (just like previously you had to use Qt's internal pre-processing macros like `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` for making connections).

Qt 5.1 already provides its own implementation for making smart pointers for [QSharedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsharedpointer.html#create).

That static [`create`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsharedpointer.html#create) member function can be used as follows:

```
auto ptr = QSharedPointer<QPushButton>::create("Cancel", this);
```

But note the description:

> Note: This function is **only available with a C++11** compiler that supports perfect forwarding of an arbitrary number of arguments. If the compiler does not support the necessary C++11 features, you must use the overload that calls the default constructor.

There are two major advantages of using `make_shared` and `create` functions rather than directly calling constructor with allocating memory with `new`:

1. That special perfectly forwarding function can allocate in a *single* system call a memory for both *stored object* and *reference counter*.
2. The memory allocation is separated from the calling context, so you avoid memory leaks in case of an exception is thrown while constructing another object in e.g. a function call (where a compiler is free to choose the order in which arguments are evaluated). Consider:

   ```
    foo(QSharedPointer<QPushButton>(new QPushButton("Cancel", this)), MayThrow());
   ```

That is, if the compiler first executes the `new QPushButton("Cancel", this)` expression, and then calls the `MayThrow()` function before calling the constructor of `QSharedPointer`, you may leak memory if the `MayThrow()` function throws an exception.

Comment: I actually know why `make_shared` is good, thanks, my question is not about that :) `QSharedPointer::create` is the essential part of your answer. Do you have any thoughts about this approach for `QPointer`?

Comment: @Mikhail `QPointer` seems to be deprecated, just like STL's `auto_ptr` is (and I guess for the same reasons). `QPointer` is copyable so you can write your own implementation of `make_qpointer`, since it lacks that feature, but as a general rule you should avoid deprecated types. And for `QScopedPointer` I guess it lacks this feature since it is not copyable by definition and not moveable prior to C++11 (move was introduced in Qt5.2)

Comment: Are you sure that QPointer is deprecated? Please, check http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27510

Comment: @Mikhail it might have been *undeprecated*, but `QPointer` does not hold ownership of the object pointed to, so providing something like `make_qpointer` might not be useful for all cases at all

Comment: `QPointer` is not supposed to be used as `QSharedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. It is supposed to contain a pointer to `QObject` that automatically sets to `null` when that `QObject` is destroyed. It is more similar to `std::weak_ptr` and does not own the pointer.

Comment: @SiyuanRen that's what I said, it "does not hold ownership". the only useful usecase of `make_qpointer` would be to call it with `this` argument, like `make_qpointer<QLabel>(this)`, not very useful at all

Comment: @PiotrS. As long as `QPointer` is useful, `make_qpointer` is also useful. Because it will hide `new` operator and make sure `new` is called only for something that inherits `QObject`. Qt users do a lot of `new`'s, but in this way we can be sure `new` is used only in Qt context.

Comment: @Mikhail You would still need a naked `delete` in that case. "As long as `X` is useful, `make_x` is also useful" does not hold for all `X`.

Comment: @Oktalist Not necessarily. Only when we want explicit delete. Parent will delete this object anyway.

Comment: @Mikhail Nice assumption. What if the parent is `nullptr`?

Comment: @Oktalist I thought it will be deleted when program is shutting down. Am I wrong? Will it be a leak?

Comment: @Mikhail All memory leaks will be cleaned up when the program terminates. If you're prepared to rely on that then you don't need to care about smart pointers at all.